# jQuery & Enabled/Disabled Controls

Tags: jquery

I took from somewhere the following *script* which clears all input controls in the 'mainFrm' form:

```
$(':text , textarea , #mainFrm').val('');
$('select option:nth-child(1) , #mainFrm').attr('selected', 'selected');
$(':checkbox , :radio , #mainFrm').removeAttr('checked');
```

It works really nice, but the problem is that is clears all controls regardless of the fact that some of them may be disabled. I would like to clear only the enabled ones, leaving the disables ones alone. How can I accomplish this? I tried changing the first line to

```
$(':text , textarea , enabled , #mainFrm').val('');
$(':text:enabled , textarea , #mainFrm').val('');
$(':enabled, text , textarea , #mainFrm').val('');
```

but none of them worked. Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter your other selectors:

```
$('(input:text , textarea , #mainFrm):enabled')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific selector, just for this case: http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/

Comment: He's aware of that, but doesn't know how to use it.

Comment: $(':enabled').val(''); should work. Adding 'text, textarea' and all that will change every one of that type rather than just the enabled ones. A comma in a selector is additional selectors, not predicated on the ones that came before it.